# Could use advice in making my query smarter

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Hi Guys I have the following query but the unions make it quite heavy so could anyone help in fixing my query.
There are 3 scenarios.
1. pack_no = pack of an item (inside packitem)
2. item = item inside pack (inside packitem)
3. item = doesn't have pack (inside item_master)

```
SELECT DISTINCT item, loc FROM
(SELECT e.pack_no item, g.store loc
 FROM dc_store_ranging a
 JOIN store g
   ON g.store_name_secondary = CAST(a.loc AS VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)) AND
      g.store_close_date >= SYSDATE
 LEFT JOIN dc_pim_export_vert b
        ON a.dpac = b.dpac AND b.artikel_type_LMS NOT IN ('S','V')
 LEFT JOIN dc_ccn190_sid_vtb c ON a.dpac = c.dpac
 JOIN item_master d
   ON (b.item = d.item OR c.item = d.item) AND d.status = 'A'
 LEFT JOIN packitem e
   ON (b.item = e.pack_no or c.item = e.pack_no) AND d.item = e.pack_no
 WHERE d.item NOT IN
      (SELECT f.item
       FROM item_attributes f
       WHERE f.sh_store_order_unit = 'N' AND f.sh_trade_unit = 'Y')
 UNION
 SELECT e.item, g.store loc
 FROM dc_store_ranging a
 JOIN store g
   ON g.store_name_secondary = CAST(a.loc AS VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)) AND
      g.store_close_date >= SYSDATE
 LEFT JOIN dc_pim_export_vert b
        ON a.dpac = b.dpac AND b.artikel_type_LMS NOT IN ('S','V')
 LEFT JOIN dc_ccn190_sid_vtb c ON a.dpac = c.dpac
 JOIN item_master d
   ON (b.item = d.item OR c.item = d.item) AND d.status = 'A'
 LEFT JOIN packitem e
        ON (b.item = e.pack_no or c.item = e.pack_no)
 WHERE e.item NOT IN
      (SELECT f.item
       FROM item_attributes f
       WHERE f.sh_store_order_unit = 'N' AND f.sh_trade_unit = 'Y')
 UNION
 SELECT d.item, g.store loc
 FROM dc_store_ranging a
 JOIN store g
   ON g.store_name_secondary = CAST(a.loc AS VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)) AND
      g.store_close_date >= SYSDATE
 LEFT JOIN dc_pim_export_vert b
        ON a.dpac = b.dpac AND b.artikel_type_LMS NOT IN ('S','V')
 LEFT JOIN dc_ccn190_sid_vtb c ON a.dpac = c.dpac
 JOIN item_master d
   ON (b.item = d.item OR c.item = d.item) AND d.status = 'A'
WHERE d.item NOT IN
      (SELECT f.item
       FROM item_attributes f
       WHERE f.sh_store_order_unit = 'N' and f.sh_trade_unit = 'Y')
);
```

Comment: If you want people spend time on your question you should put a little more effort in it. What is your table structure for instance?

Comment: make it heavy? what does it mean?

Comment: My eyes are bleeding from the horrible formatting of this query.

Comment: This is hardly a [Short Self-Contained Correct Example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). Basically, no one's going to help you unless you reduce your query to the absolute minimum that shows the issue. There's just too much crap here to wade through.

Comment: @Bohemian: Only us masochists... Basically, elimination of crap seems to be the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to improve the performance of the query would be to change the `UNION`s to `UNION ALL`s - that way, the query only has to eliminate duplicates once.

However, it should be possible to simplify this query to:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT d.item d_item, e.item e_item, e.pack_no e_pack_no, g.store loc
 FROM dc_store_ranging a
 JOIN store g
   ON g.store_name_secondary = CAST(a.loc AS VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)) AND
      g.store_close_date >= SYSDATE
 LEFT JOIN dc_pim_export_vert b
        ON a.dpac = b.dpac AND b.artikel_type_LMS NOT IN ('S','V')
 LEFT JOIN dc_ccn190_sid_vtb c ON a.dpac = c.dpac
 JOIN item_master d
   ON (b.item = d.item OR c.item = d.item) AND d.status = 'A'
 LEFT JOIN packitem e
        ON (b.item = e.pack_no or c.item = e.pack_no)
)
SELECT DISTINCT item, loc FROM
(--SELECT e_pack_no item, loc FROM CTE WHERE d_item = e_pack_no UNION ALL -- this select is a subset of the third select
 SELECT e_item item, loc FROM CTE UNION ALL
 SELECT d_item item, loc FROM CTE) uc
WHERE uc.item NOT IN
      (SELECT f.item
       FROM item_attributes f
       WHERE f.sh_store_order_unit = 'N' and f.sh_trade_unit = 'Y')
```